# Determine potential coordinates for point $A$ on the terminal arm if angle $\theta$ lies in Quadrant $2$ with $\sin\theta = 3/\sqrt{45}$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to learn how to complete questions like these but when I look at the equation all I think I can do is simplify $\sqrt{45}$ into $3\sqrt{5}$. What do I do next? It says quadrant $2$, so the sin must be positive and everything else negative...

$\sin\theta= \dfrac{y}{r}$, so I have one $y$-coordinate (3), but what about $x$?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I'll use that format next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is to use the Pythagorean identity $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$.
\begin{align*}
\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta & = 1\\
\cos^2\theta & = 1 - \sin^2\theta\\
|\cos\theta| & = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}
\end{align*}
Since $\theta$ is a second-quadrant angle, $\cos\theta < 0$.
$$\cos\theta = -\sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}$$
Finding $\cos\theta$ will tell you the $x$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle.  We know that the $y$-coordinate of that point is $\sin\theta$.

If you wish to find the $x$-coordinate of the point at which the terminal side of the angle intersects the circle with radius $\sqrt{45} = 3\sqrt{5}$, you will have to scale the $x$-coordinate you find by $3\sqrt{5}$.

Another way would be to draw a right triangle in the second quadrant with opposite side $3$ and hypotenuse $3\sqrt{5}$.  You can then use the Pythagorean Theorem to find the magnitude of the $x$-coordinate.  Just keep in mind that the $x$-coordinate must be negative.

[image: trigonometry_diagram]

Comment: Would the x-coordinate be -6?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much!